# How to hide some columns on toggle button in ui grid in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

My ui grid loads with 10 columns.Based on toggle button. I need to make visible property false for 5 columns and ui should load with 5 columns. How to achieve programmatically

Answer (score 0):

this is totally logic based question and totally depends on the developer how to handle this. 
if you are showing your div dynamically you can add one object named as checked and set it true for first 5 and false for other 5. on toggle button you can make that first 5 false or second 5 true or you can handle in the way want using *ngIf condition on div.

if your div is not loading dynamically and they are hardcoded div, you can simply add 2 variable making them true or false and show div using ngIf.

Answer (score 0):

in controller have a scope variable

$scope.show5Column = true; (Default will show those column)

and just add the ng-show property in the HTML tag which contain the grid column classes.

ng-show="show5column"

on toggle button, change the value of scope variable